# Fuzzing shared libraries using libfuzzer

Tags: android, stagefright, fuzzer

The fuzzing process using libfuzzer continues indefinitely until a bug is found.

Is there a flag or an option in libfuzzer to mutate and continue fuzzing even after discovering a bug ?

Answer (score 3):

ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=0 may be helpful

AddressSanitizer has recently got continue-after-error mode. This is somewhat experimental so may not yet be as reliable as default setting (and not as timely supported). Also keep in mind that errors after the first one may actually be spurious.

AddressSanitizer WIKI is [here](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer)

Comment: hello, i want to know that can i set a running time to the libfuzzer and it can run until the time?